# How to create a new Xcode Project in folder under version control

Tags: xcode, git

I have created a new repository in Github, set up the readme.md/.gitignore etc and cloned it to my Mac at `user/project`.

If when creating the project in Xcode I select `user/project` as the folder the project is created in `user/project/project`.

If when creating the project in Xcode I select `user` as the folder the project is created in `user/project`, however the folder has been overwritten, losing the link to Github and existing files. I am also unable to clone the git repository in to this new folder.

Is it possible to create a new Xcode project in a folder under version control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really in a convenient way. Generally the easiest way to get what you want is to create the project outside of git (without creating a new repo), and then just move everything into the git directories. (That said, 90% of time I forget to do that and just make inside the git directory and then rearrange things.)

Comment: Thanks, I ended up rearranging things inside the directory - of course I only thought of that after pressing submit on the question... Glad I wasn't missing something else obvious though.

Comment: I noticed that by rearranging things in the folder I needed to tidy up the files in Git, so creating it in a separate folder and moving it in is better.